# Displaying bitmaps

Tags: android, android-bitmap

I need help with displaying a bitmap. I am using a class which is extending Activity. Where would I put this?

```
Mybitmap = BitMapfactory.decode resource(getresource,R.drawable.bit);
```

Also how would I draw it on the screen?

Answer (score 0):

you should use ImageView...

put ImageView in you layout with "myImage" id and in activity do like this :

```
ImageView mImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImage);
mImg.setImageBitmap(Mybitmap);
```

Comment: I forgot to tell u but I don't have an XML file I just have 2 java files the layout and activity

Comment: your layout file is xml type .
please post those

Comment: You can create imageview with bitmap and call Setcontentview(imageview)